# In Rstudio, do I have to press arrow to move the pointer out of the autocompleted quotation mark?

Tags: rstudio

In Rstudio if you type a quotation mark, it will automatically complete the end quotation mark and the pointer is inside the two quotation marks. I currently need to move my hand to another side of the keyboard to press "arrow" to move the pointer out of the quotation marks. Is there any hotkey can do so without having my hand leave the keyboard?Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think I accidentally found the answer: if you are in a parenthesis, after you finished whatever you want to put here, type then end parenthesis, the pointer will come out. If you are in a quotation mark, type another quotation mark to get out, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

On OS X, you can use `Ctrl + F` to move to the next character; alternatively, you can activate Vim keybindings and use `l`; with Emacs keybindings you should be able to use `Ctrl + F` regardless of operating system.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I'm using win10, Ctrl+F will give me the search box